# how to save user input string in init()

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand how to save the input string and then for in init() to later use it in another function

```
Class Person: 
   def __init__ (self):
    ....

   def cCount (self):
    num_A = self.count('A') 
    return num_A                       

import sys
def main():
inX = input('sequence?')
while inX 
    myY = Person(inX)
    myCnumber = myY.cCount()
    print (" {0}".format(myCnumber))
    ...
```

I want the output to be the count the number of As in the user input string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange your code a little bit like this to achieve what you want:

```
class Person: 
   def __init__ (self, sequence):
       self.sequence = sequence

   def cCount (self):
       return self.sequence.count('A')

import sys
def main():
    inX = input('sequence?')
    while inX:
        myY = Person(inX)
        myCnumber = myY.cCount()
        print (" {0}".format(myCnumber))
        inX = input('sequence?')

main()
```

**Result**

```
sequence?ABCDEF
 1
sequence?XAAAEWF
 3
sequence?
```

**Changes made**

- Class was replaced with class - lowercase
- Init definition added with sequence parameter
- Inside init added `self.sequence` and initialized it
- In `def cCount`, changed to self.sequence.count('A') and returned it
- Indented def main's body
- Added colon after inX
- added inX = input.. at the bottom of while so that while can continue until you just hit Enter